# Как заменить пробелы в строке?

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
$str = '<h2 id="name of header">Name of header</h2>';
```

Мне необходимо заменить все пробелы на символ '-' только в параметре ID (id="name of header"). Как это сделать?

Comment: Браузер и с пробелами съест. А заменять раньше надо было.

Comment: мне не для браузера надо. зачем писать пустые советы?

Comment: А почему бы их и не писать? Я ж не в ответе это написал.

Comment: Действительно, какова конечная цель и откуда исходная строка?

Comment: Изначально есть просто тег <h2>Name of header</h2> . С помощью preg_replace подставляется ID к этому тегу с его содержимым. Цель заменить в id параметре все пробелы на -

Comment: Вот код, который добавляет id к тегу: $str= preg_replace("/(<h.)(>)(.*.)(<\/h.>)/", "$1 id='$3'$2$3$4", $str);

Comment: @Антон добавил вам ответ с  preg_replace_callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте функцию preg_replace_callback. Для вашего примера:

```
$str = '<h2 id="name of header">Name of header</h2><h3 id="name of header">Name of header</h3>';

$str = preg_replace_callback('/id="([^"]+)"/',
    function ($matches) {
            return 'id="'.str_replace(' ', '-', $matches[1]).'"';
        },$str);

        echo $str;
```

результат:

```
<h2 id="name-of-header">Name of header</h2><h3 id="name-of-header">Name of header</h3>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже использую точно такое же решение =) Конечно этот способ гораздо лучше чем который предложил я раньше.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы воспользовался str_relace

`$str = '<h2 id="name of header">Name of header</h2>';
 $str = str_replace(" ", "-", $str);
 echo $str;`

Comment: это заменит во всей строке, в итоге будет <h2-d="name-of-header">Name-of-header</h2> Мне надо только в ID

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем если кому-то надо сделать похожую задачу, вот решение на мой вопрос:

```
$content = explode("\r\n", $content); //разбиваем контент на строки

foreach ($content as $str) { // перебираем полученные массив
    if ( preg_match("/(<h. id=.*.)(>)(.*.)(<\/h.>)/", $str) == 1 ) { //если текущая строка содержит любой тег h1-h6
        $id = preg_replace("/(<h. id=.*.)(>)(.*.)(<\/h.>)/", "$3", $str); // выбираем только то, что лежит в id
        $bad_symbols = array(" ", ","); // задаем символы, которые необходимо заменить
        $id = trim(str_replace($bad_symbols, "-", $id)); //заменяем ненужные символы предварительно удалив пробелы побокам
        $str = preg_replace("/(<h. id=)(.*.)(>)(.*.)(<\/h.>)/", "$1'".$id."'$3$4$5", $str); // собираем отформатированную строку
    }
    echo $str; // выводим готовый контент
}
```

Comment: это фарш, а не решение

Comment: это решает мою задачу. тем более что других вариантов здесь нет

Comment: всё это можно решить одним регулярным выражением.
Конструкции вида `(.*.)` бессмысленны, надеюсь разберётесь почему.

Comment: есть пример хоть один?